# Liferay success message for uploading a file

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to add my own success message on liferay after uploading a file.
in my view.jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:success key="key1" message="message1" />
```

I created a package in src folder named: "content". in whish I created a file: language.properties.
language.properties:

```
message1=file uploaded successfully
```

in my controller:

```
SessionMessages.add(uploadRequest, "key1");
```

but that doesn't work. it display the liferay default message. please help.

Comment: Do you mean that language key is not getting resolved?

Comment: thanks for response.Yes, exactely. language key is not getting resolved

Comment: Have you specified resource-bundle entry in portlet.xml properly?

Comment: No I didn't. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have not specified resource-bundle entry in portlet.xml.

In portlet.xml provide `<resource-bundle>content.language</resource-bundle>`